# Plesk JXcore fails installing NPM Modules

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js, plesk

When trying to add a Node Module over the Plesk JXcore Interface it fails with the message.
I can't even access the jx command over SSH.

> error: Cannot install sails module. Wrong user id of the command.

[image: Plesk JXcore]

Comment: Which operating system ?

Comment: It's CentOS 6 with Plesk 12

Comment: @harrisG As far as I understand, Plesk Panel runs php as psaadm user. Do you have any idea, how is this in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but infografnet already answered the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, early morning, new version of JXcore support Plesk's extension was published: [0.2.0](http://ext.plesk.com/packages/28f799af-1ff4-4bb8-9c87-a04f0f23d32e-jxcore-support).

Among many things there are some improvements related with NPM modules installations, also your case with "Wrong user id of the command" was taken care of. This wasn't a bug actually. Rather a result of redundant permission check and you were the first to encounter this.

Also there is a new feature which allows to enable/disable JXcore support for entire subscription or all of them at once.

Comment: I would like to test it, but I've allready switched to shell, rather than plesk